# numpy: random select K items from total M(M>K) items?

Tags: matlab, numpy, random

Is there some handy implementation of Matlab function randperm in numpy that random select K items from totally M(M>K) items, and return the selected indice?

In Matlab,

```
randperm(100,10)

ans =

82    90    13    89    61    10    27    51    97    88
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the [`numpy.random.choice` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice).

```
>>> numpy.random.choice(100, 10, replace=False)
array([89, 99, 27, 39, 80, 31,  6,  0, 40, 93])
```

Note that the resulting range is 0 to M-1. If you need 1 to M like MATLAB, add `1` to the result:

```
>>> numpy.random.choice(100, 10, replace=False) + 1
array([ 28,  23,  15,  90,  18,  65,  86, 100,  99,   1])
```

Comment: great, it helps me :-